# MySQL manually add id in clause "WHERE IN (SELECT ...)"

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * from t1
WHERE child_id IN (SELECT child_id from t2 WHERE parent_id='1234')
OR parent_id='1234'
```

is it possible to do something like this:

```
SELECT * from t1
WHERE child_id IN (
    (SELECT child_id from t2 WHERE parent_id='1234')
    UNION '5678'
)
```

The `UNION` keyword gives an error message and I tried searching on google but it's hard to find something when you search "Mysql concat IN"

I hope my question is clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, like this:

```
SELECT * from t1
WHERE child_id IN 
(
  SELECT child_id from t2 WHERE parent_id='1234'
  UNION  
  SELECT 5678
)
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Fast answer! Note for others: I put the first SELECT in parentheses and it did not work, had to remove them

Comment: Sorry it took so long, StackOverflow would not permit me to accept before a certain amount of time

Comment: @user2681072 No problem, I thought you don't know how it works here, thanks and welcome to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

The queries are different (I mean the example and the one with the error), but you can do:

```
SELECT * from t1
WHERE child_id IN (SELECT child_id from t2 WHERE parent_id='1234'
                   union all
                   select '5678'
                  );
```